# How to decode string using unkown algorithm?

Tags: http, encode, mojibake

I use Fiddler capture http request, but meet mojibake in http body.

[mojibake http request img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izNQo.png)

I copy the http body as bas64 encode and try to know what it is.

There is the base64 encode string:

```
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
```

There is my php code:

```
<?php

$b64Encode = "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";

$str = base64_decode($b64Encode);
$str = gzdecode($str);

var_dump($str);
file_put_contents('d:/123.txt', $str);

$enclist = array( 
            'UTF-8', 'ASCII', 
            'ISO-8859-1', 'ISO-8859-2', 'ISO-8859-3', 'ISO-8859-4', 'ISO-8859-5', 
            'ISO-8859-6', 'ISO-8859-7', 'ISO-8859-8', 'ISO-8859-9', 'ISO-8859-10', 
            'ISO-8859-13', 'ISO-8859-14', 'ISO-8859-15', 'ISO-8859-16', 
            'Windows-1251', 'Windows-1252', 'Windows-1254', 'GBK', 'GB2312',
            );
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($str, $enclist));


$str2 = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $str);
var_dump($str2);
```

[php result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdz8D.png)

It is already mojibake. How to decode it?

Comment: What makes you think it is a text in the first place? It looks like a binary file to me.

Comment: @Jan Hudec Becase I gzip decode the string and it contains something like `[{"configured":[{"priority":0,"name":"\"WiredSSID\"","networkId":0}]}]`.

Comment: That can still be part of otherwise binary file. Program machine (or JVM) code often contains many string constants that are readable text. And a lot of other content that isn't.

Comment: @JanHudec Yep, you're right. But I find the file signatures in [this website](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html). Not found anything about it. I think it is not a regular file.